# sum up value from multiple subdocuments in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following datastructure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e96f771e016b98aa63d88c9"),
  "goals" : {
    "4809" : {
      "VisitsBeforeGoal" : 12,
      "pagesBeforeGoal" : 16
    },
    "4810" : {
      "VisitsBeforeGoal" : 2,
      "pagesBeforeGoal" : 6
    },
    "4811" : {
      "VisitsBeforeGoal" : 3,
      "pagesBeforeGoal" : 8
    }
  },
  "totalPages" : 246,
  "totalVisits" : 114
}
```

4809, 4810 and 4811 is goalID's that are not know, e.g. dynamic.

Now what i want is to get the sum of "VisitsBeforeGoal" on each goal and "pagesBeforeGoal" and a sum of goals. Something like:

```
{
  goals:[
    {
          "goalID" : 4809,
          "VisitsBeforeGoal" : 245,
          "pagesBeforeGoal" : 632,
          "sum" : 45,    
    }
  ]
}
```

I cant seem to figure out how to get into each subdocument, as i dont know the goalID. I tried somehting like "goals.$.VisitsBeforeGoal" but that did not seem to work.

Comment: can you query before aggregation to get all goal keys?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Yes. I can use a map/reduce to get this info in my script. Any ideas then?

Comment: if you know field names then you can do it with aggregation. I'll post an example later today.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is problematical. In order to  make `goals.$.VisitsBeforeGoal` work, you need an array. So your structure must be

```
"goals" : [ {
        "id" : 4809,
        "VisitsBeforeGoal" : 12,
        "pagesBeforeGoal" : 16
    },
    {
        "id" : 4810,
        "VisitsBeforeGoal" : 2,
        "pagesBeforeGoal" : 6
    },
    {
        "id" : 4811,
        "VisitsBeforeGoal" : 3,
        "pagesBeforeGoal" : 8
    }
]
```

Working with dynamic keys is not a good choice. If you have chance to change your structure, I would advice you to change it.

Comment: The reason for this datastructure is that i need to $inc multiple goals in same query like: {$inc:{goals.4810.pageBeforeGoal:3,goals.4811.pageBeforeGoal:6}} so therefore i cannot use $elemMatch if goals where an array.

Comment: right - using goals as keys allows simple update/upsert - the schema you propose is easier to query but hard to update. See flip side problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032339/mongodb-inc-of-a-nonexistent-document-in-an-array?noredirect=1#comment29922537_20032339