# mongoDB: $inc of a nonexistent document in an array

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, increment

I was not able to write a code, which would be able to increment a non-existent value in an array.

Let's consider a following structure in a mongo collection. (This is not the actual structure we use, but it maintains the issue)

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("527400e43ca8e0f79c2ce52c"),
        "content" : "Blotted Science",
        "tags_with_ratings" : [
                {
                        "ratings" : {
                                "0" : 6154,
                                "1" : 4974
                        },
                        "tag_name" : "math_core"
                },
                {
                        "ratings" : {
                                "0" : 154,
                                "1" : 474,
                        },
                        "tag_name" : "progressive_metal"
                }
        ]
}
```

Example issue: We want to add to this document into the tags_with_ratings attribute an incrementation of a rating of a tag, which is not yet added in the array. For example we would want to increment a "0" value for a tag_name "dubstep".

So the expected behaviour would be, that mongo would upsert a document like this into the "tags_with_ratings" attribute:

```
            {
                    "ratings" : {
                            "0" : 1
                    },
                    "tag_name" : "dubstep"
            }
```

At the moment, we need to have one read operation, which checks if the nested document for the tag is there. If it's not, we pull the array tags_with_ratings out, create a new one, re-add the values from the previous one and add the new nested document in there. Shouldn't we be able to do this with one upsert operation, without having the expensive read happen?

The incrementation of the values takes up 90% of the process and more than half of it is consumed by reading, because we are unable to use $inc capability of creating an attribute, if it is non-existent in the array.

Comment: you cannot do it with one step using this schema.  You could if you used tag_name as the key name instead of using "ratings" there, but then you may have a different issue when querying.

Comment: When you are incrementing ratings, is the document itself guaranteed to exist?

Comment: Do you know tag_names in advance or are they dynamic?

Comment: Hi, (thanks for the effort to question) the tag_namese are not known. New can and will be created at runtime and added into the structure. So the document is not guaranteed to exist. I would like it to be created with the name and the initial rating, which was added for it for the first time, into the array. 

What do you mean by "key name"?

Comment: in json the key value pairs - { k:v } the name of the field is the key name (or field name).  So if the tag_name value was instead the field name (replacing ratings) you'd have {"dubstep":{"0":1}} which you can update dynamically the way you want to.  But that makes it more difficult to query - see this question which uses the other schema and has a different problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996622/sum-up-value-from-multiple-subdocuments-in-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment29901545_19996622

Comment: also when I asked if the document is guaranteed to exist - I meant the top level object - would the top level object exist (so there is an array to either add this new sub-object to or not.

Comment: The array is guaranteed to exist - tags_with_ratings will be there, even if it is empty. Or at least it is easy for us to do guarantee it, if it helps. 

Thank you for the suggestion, strange the option did not come to mind. I am going to look through the stack question you offered and discuss with a colleague this new option you offered.

Comment: Also we will not need to do any aggregation across the contents of the array. Our only queries will be to get the ratings for a specific tag_name, so your solution seems like is the thing we were looking for. Now what would we lose/gain, by not using an array, but a document with sub-documents like {"dubstep":{"0":1}}? We had an array because the keys would repeat, but now it seems unnecessary.

Comment: there are aggregations and queries which would be limited now - there is no way to say "give me all of activities/tags/etc".  If you will always be reading the whole document, there's not much downside.

Comment: If you wish to receive reputation for your helpful answer, which became the solution for me (changing array to document with keys being the tags), please write it below, so that I can rate it up and choose it as best answer afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve what you want with one step using this schema.

You could do it however if you used `tag_name` as the key name instead of using `ratings` there, but then you may have a different issue when querying.

If the tag_name value was the field name (replacing ratings) you'd have `{"dubstep":{"0":1}}` instead of `{ "ratings" : {"0" : 1},"tag_name" : "dubstep"}` which you can update dynamically the way you want to. Just keep in mind that this schema will make it more difficult to query - you have to know what the ratings are in advance to be able to query by keyname.